# Linking texture to scripting file in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity3D. I am planning to build a basic car game for android using Unity3D. I am not able to create a GUI texture and link it to the scripting file. Anyone here can teach me how to code the file or post a link to a site which teaches me the basics. I have referred to Unity3D manual, din't understand well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a couple of webs with basic unity training

[Walker boys](http://walkerboystudio.com/html/unity_training___free__.html)

[unity3dstudent](http://www.unity3dstudent.com)

anyway the best place to post unity3d questions is this :

[Unity answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html)

Comment: Is it related to android, because i am fedup watching vids related to standalone platform. I need a site which can teach me how to build a basic android app.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript:

```
var yourTexture: Texture;
```

In C#

```
public Texture2D yourTexture;
```

They need to be public. After you assign the Script to your GameObject, you will be able to set the Texture in the Project Inspector.